# Why does changing the x value make the the line move up or down?

Tags: highcharts

Why does the following code change the y value on my line graph instead of the x value?  (By changing the y value, I mean the line moves up or down, not side to side)

```
chart.series[0].data[0].update(x = xMin);
```

The series was originally loaded with the following setup

```
series: [{
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Regression Line',
    data: [[0, 1.11], [5, 4.51]],
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    states: {
        hover: {
            lineWidth: 0
        }
    },
    enableMouseTracking: false
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update** `([Mixed options], [Boolean redraw], [Mixed animation])`
Update the point with new values.

**Parameters**

- **options**: `Number|Array|Object`
  The point options. **If options is a single number, the point will be given that number as the y value**.If it is an array, it will be interpreted as x and y values respectively. If it is an object, advanced options as outlined under series.data are applied.
- **redraw**: `Boolean`
  Defaults to true. Whether to redraw the chart after the point is updated.If doing more operations on the chart, it is a good idea to set redraw to false and call chart.redraw() after.
- **animation**: `Mixed`
  Defaults to true. When true, the update will be animated with default animationoptions. The animation can also be a configuration object with properties durationand easing.

[**Source**](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Point.update%28%29)

So, change to the following:

```
chart.series[0].data[0].update({x: 3});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/Eybb7/)